# HLS MP4 Independent Segments

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, http-live-streaming, m3u8, fmp4

Long story short: Why HLS can't just play normal MP4 files together one after one? Why need to segment media file into .ts segments?

**Details:**

We've segmented MP4 file into mini MP4 segments (not TS), each one about 30 seconds for testing. It never plays in any HLS player, just loading all segment files then nothing happens.

**Example MP4 segment Info:**

```
Format                      : MPEG-4
Format profile              : Base Media
Codec ID                    : isom
File size                   : 1.44 MiB
Duration                    : 32s 950ms
Overall bit rate            : 366 Kbps
Writing application         : Lavf56.25.101

Video
ID                          : 1
Format                      : AVC
Format/Info                 : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile              : High@L4.1
Format settings, CABAC      : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames   : 6 frames
Codec ID                    : avc1
Codec ID/Info               : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                    : 32s 950ms
Bit rate                    : 230 Kbps
Width                       : 426 pixels
Height                      : 240 pixels
Display aspect ratio        : 16:9
Original display aspect rat : 16:9
Frame rate mode             : Constant
Frame rate                  : 23.976 fps
Color space                 : YUV
Chroma subsampling          : 4:2:0
Bit depth                   : 8 bits
Scan type                   : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)          : 0.094
Stream size                 : 925 KiB (63%)
Writing library             : x264 core 142 r2495 6a301b6

Audio
ID                          : 2
Format                      : AAC
Format/Info                 : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile              : LC
Codec ID                    : 40
Duration                    : 32s 896ms
Bit rate mode               : Constant
Bit rate                    : 129 Kbps
Channel(s)                  : 2 channels
Channel(s)_Original         : 6 channels
Channel positions           : Front: L C R, Side: L R, LFE
Sampling rate               : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode            : Lossy
Stream size                 : 517 KiB (35%)
```

**The Master M3U8:**

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:7
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:RESOLUTION=426x240,BANDWIDTH=370000,CODECS="avc1.640015,mp4a.40.2"
240p.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:RESOLUTION=640x360,BANDWIDTH=580000,CODECS="avc1.640015,mp4a.40.2"
360p.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:RESOLUTION=896x504,BANDWIDTH=900000,CODECS="avc1.640015,mp4a.40.2"
480p.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:RESOLUTION=1280x720,BANDWIDTH=1500000,CODECS="avc1.640015,mp4a.40.2"
720p.m3u8
```

**240p.m3u8**

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:7
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:34

#EXTINF:33.033033,
240p000.mp4
#EXTINF:33.533534,
240p001.mp4
#EXTINF:24.941608,
240p002.mp4
#EXTINF:28.611945,
240p003.mp4
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

**When tested with HLS.js, gives this error:**

> Parsing Error:no demux matching with content found,cannot recover,
>   last media error recovery failed ...

Bitmovin Player: loads all segments of all variants and never plays any of them. just stop.

Tested on Chrome & Firefox On Windows, Safari on Mac, Android and iPad Browsers. Never works on any of them. Are we doing anything wrong?!

Comment: Why questions are opinion based. Apple chose ts and (fragmented mp4 in ios10) for the format. You will need to ask them why they chose it. Nobody here can answer that. So I guess your answer is, "Because it not supported"

Comment: @szatmary it's not opinion based. I'm just asking if it is possible or not.Is there any method or solution to avoid double space of each video file (source MP4 + TS Segments).

Comment: The question you asked was "Why HLS can't just play normal MP4 files together one after one?" That IS opinion based. If you asked "Can HLS play normal MP4 files"? It would not be opinion based. And the answer would be No. But starting with iOS10 it will play fragmented mp4 files.

Answer (score 2):

While transport stream segments are self-initializing, this is usually/often not the case for fMP4 segments. Therefore, you will need to add the initialization segment to the manifest file, which is needed to initialize the decoder. This can be done using the #EXT-X-MAP:URI tag as shown in the image of [this blog post](https://bitmovin.com/hls-news-wwdc-2016/) and in the example below:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:4
#EXT-X-VERSION:7
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="init.mp4"

#EXTINF:4.0
segment_0.m4s
#EXTINF:4.0
segment_1.m4s
...
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

I'm not sure about HLS.js, but this should work at least for the Bitmovin Player. If not I'd recommend to use Bitmovin's support.

Apple also provides a [test page with fMP4 HLS](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/examples/) (requires native HLS support in the browser, such in Safari), and Bitmovin has a [demo page with fMP4 HLS](https://bitmovin.com/hls-fragmented-mp4/) avialable.

Comment: HLS with fmp4 is actually pretty useful and works already on iOS10, macOS and tvOS. Here you can find also an end to end tutorial for creating fmp4 HLS content and playback: https://bitmovin.com/halve-encoding-packaging-storage-costs-hls-fragmented-mp4/

Answer (score 0):

> Why HLS can't just play normal MP4 files together one after one? Why need to segment media file into .ts segments?

MP4 files have a whole container that you don't really want or need.  Each segment could in theory contain its own number of audio and video tracks, each with its own formats, frame rates, sample rates, etc.  You don't need all of that, and you also need to stick video segments together cleanly.  Therefore, you need something to encode segments cleanly in the first place.

Comment: So we need to avoid double space of each video (Source MP4 + TS Segments) Is there any method to parse MP4 file and reply with the requested fragment on real time without re-encoding?

Comment: We've tried #EXT-X-BYTERANGE but it didn't work also. Does it have media format restrictions?!

Comment: I would use FFmpeg to re-mux (not transcode) the file.  This has very little overhead, and doesn't modify the actual media data at all.

Answer (score 0):

FFMPEG has supported to generate fragment MP4 for HLS now. Take a look at https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5699